# Mysql SUBSTRING_INDEX() for fetching value after "-"

Tags: mysql, substring

i have following query

```
   SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.`val1`,' ',-3) AS Value1,
   MAX(table1.`Covered Charges`) AS `Max Covered Charges`
   FROM table1
```

but this dosent seem to work,I have result like this

```
                   Value1                               Max Covered Charges           
    0604 - Level 1 Hospital Clinic Visits                118.320653298836
    0605 - Level 2 Hospital Clinic Visits                134.270025695931
    0013 - Level II Debridement & Destruction            146.626388077148
    0368 - Level II Pulmonary Tests                      188.440063091483
    0015 - Level III Debridement & Destruction           190.02526119403
    0607 - Level 4 Hospital Clinic Visits                220.876543209877
    0606 - Level 3 Hospital Clinic Visits                224.089367424242
```

what i want is some thing like this

```
                   Value1                        Max Covered Charges           
    Level 1 Hospital Clinic Visits               118.320653298836
    Level 2 Hospital Clinic Visits               134.270025695931
    Level II Debridement & Destruction           146.626388077148
    Level II Pulmonary Tests                     188.440063091483
    Level III Debridement & Destruction          190.02526119403
    Level 4 Hospital Clinic Visits               220.876543209877
    Level 3 Hospital Clinic Visits               224.089367424242
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.`val1`,'-',-1)AS Value1, MAX(table1.`Covered Charges`) AS `Max Covered Charges`for Selected Hospital`
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 2):

Some example table data could help.

Try this:

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.val1,'-',-1) AS Value1...`

[Reference Manual > SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: @noobie-php . . . Your query has `-3` for the third argument.  This has `-1`.  The `-1` looks correct for your data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: doing so didnt returned desire thing all i got was raw result